# jQuery .append() in MSIE

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer, append

```
    function loadSavedSort(start) {
    start = parseInt(start);
    if ( isNaN(start) )
        start = 0;
    var listing = $("#viewsavedsort .listing");
    listing.find('.item').remove();
    var start = $('#savedSortStart').val();
    $.getJSON('saveajax.php', { 'start': start },
        function(data) {
            $("#viewsavedsort .loading").hide();
            $("#viewsavedsort .view").show();

            // Hides/shows Older button according to returned flag NEXT
            if ( data['NEXT'] ) {
                $('#viewSavedSortOlder').show();
            } else {
                $('#viewSavedSortOlder').hide();
            }

            // Hides Newer button if first page
            if ( start == 0 ) {
                $('#viewSavedSortNewer').hide();
            } else {
                $('#viewSavedSortNewer').show();
            }

            for ( key in data['DATA'] ) {
                var html = "<div class='item'>"+
                    "<div class='img ui-corner-all'>"+
                        "<a href='"+data['DATA'][key]['link']+"'><img src='JPEG_75/"+data['DATA'][key]['image']+"' /></a>"+
                    "</div>"+
                    "<div class='text'>"+
                        "<table><tr><td>"+
                        "Date Saved: "+data['DATA'][key]['date']+"<br />"+
                        "User's name: "+data['DATA'][key]['name']+"<br />"+
                        "Keywords used: "+data['DATA'][key]['keywords']+"<br />"+
                        "Total number of objects: "+data['DATA'][key]['total']+
                        "</td></tr></table>"
                    "</div></div>";
                //html += "</div>";
                listing.append(html);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

This is perfectly working in Firefox, Safari, Opera, Google Chrome,... but not in MSIE. Why?
Images are displayed, but text is missing.

Edit: Sorry, this is the first time i'm posting here. Updated code. In saveajax.php i've used json_encode() on this:

```
    $ret['DATA'][$row['id']] = array(
    'name' => stripslashes($row['name']),
    'date' => date('n/d/Y',strtotime($row['date'])),
    'keywords' => implode(" + ",$keywords),
    'total' => $total,
    'image' => $image,
    'link' => $link,
);
```

Also, I haven't got any error. It simply won't show in IE.
What made me scratch my head is images actually being displayed and linked to correct URL.

Comment: Can you provide a little context? Perhaps what exactly listing is and where/how you defined it.

Comment: the dom mibht not be avaialbe in IE by that time as you are generating the content dynamically

Comment: I'm also curious what `data['DATA']` is. Is it possible those variables simply aren't defined due to some earlier problem?

Comment: What's `listing`? What's `data`? Where is this occurring? What error do you get? Have you walked through with a debugger? In general, the more effort you put into your question, the better both the quality and quantity of the answers you'll receive (and the less of people's time you'll waste).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all those string concatenation yourself you should just use one of the client-side templating libraries.

[Here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/509108.aspx) is a nice article that explains what client-side templating is.

I've been using [jQote2](http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote2/), but will probably switch to [jQuery Templating by Microsoft](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/10/04/microsoft-templates-included-in-jquery-1-5.aspx).